# PHP - any way to log PCRE regex execution errors?

Tags: php, error-log

One of the `preg_match()` functions we were using was resulting in a `preg_last_error()`, specifically the `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR`.

However, when browsing our PHP error logs, there are no entries for this.

Is there any way to automatically log when an error occurs during PCRE regex execution, similar to how uncaught exceptions and errors are automatically logged, without adding our own custom logging code?

Update: Same concept would apply to `json_decode()` generating errors stored in `json_last_error()`.

Comment: you can always log it with [`error_log()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

Comment: Thank you, but we're looking to automatically log these errors without additional logging code, perhaps by updating php's configuration. I have updated the question to clarify this.